# Power supply protection to charge a battery

Tags: mosfet, battery-charging, reverse-polarity

I am using a power source to charge a battery. To protect the power supply from reverse polarity conection of battery I included a PMOSFET transistor like showed:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSktnf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The problem is that this only works when power supply if off. 
If the power supply is on, so transistor conduces like VGS < Vt, and if now battery is connected with reverse polarity (VBAT < 0) there is a large current flow from source to battery like a short circuit, due to the large voltage diference between  V1 and VBAT, and the transistor still conduces.

Is there some way to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noticed it won't work with your schematic, or with just a diode, because the direction of the current is the same.

So is there some way we can say "*This battery has been inserted in the wrong direction!*", why yes, that would be if we read what we think is the positive terminal of the battery as less voltage than ground. Because that should **never** happen if it has been connected correctly.

All you need for this is an op-amp acting as a simple comparator, here's an image showing a schematic illustrating my point. The one on the left is a battery being charged correctly, on the right is a battery inserted in the wrong way not taking *any* considerable current.

[image]

Here's the [link](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%209.001713130052181%2055%205%2050%0Aw%20496%20208%20496%20224%200%0Aw%20528%20208%20528%20224%200%0Aw%20560%20224%20528%20224%200%0Aw%20480%20224%20496%20224%200%0Aw%20416%20400%20592%20400%200%0AR%20416%20224%20416%20176%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20416%20224%20480%20224%201%0Ag%20416%20400%20416%20416%200%0Av%20592%20400%20592%20224%200%200%2040%204.8%200%200%200.5%0Ad%20528%20208%20496%20208%201%200.805904783%0Af%20512%20320%20512%20224%209%201.5%200.02%0Aa%20416%20320%20512%20320%200%2015%20-15%201000000%204.8%200%0Aw%20560%20224%20560%20272%200%0Aw%20560%20272%20416%20272%200%0Aw%20416%20272%20416%20304%200%0Aw%20560%20224%20592%20224%202%0Aw%20416%20336%20416%20400%200%0Aw%20640%20336%20640%20400%200%0Aw%20784%20224%20816%20224%202%0Aw%20640%20272%20640%20304%200%0Aw%20784%20272%20640%20272%200%0Aw%20784%20224%20784%20272%200%0Aa%20640%20320%20736%20320%200%2015%20-15%201000000%20-4.8%200%0Af%20736%20320%20736%20224%209%201.5%200.02%0Ad%20752%20208%20720%20208%201%200.805904783%0Av%20816%20224%20816%20400%200%200%2040%204.8%200%200%200.5%0Ag%20640%20400%20640%20416%200%0Aw%20640%20224%20704%20224%201%0AR%20640%20224%20640%20176%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20640%20400%20816%20400%200%0Aw%20704%20224%20720%20224%200%0Aw%20784%20224%20752%20224%200%0Aw%20752%20208%20752%20224%200%0Aw%20720%20208%20720%20224%200%0A) if you want to play around.